# Ошибка загрузки чанка Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

Всем привет, столкнулся с вот такой проблемой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка стала появляться после установки npm пакета "concurrently" в Node_module проекта. Вот изображение настройки package-json, concurrently находится в свойстве "serve".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так-же мне кажется что ошибка может быть в импорте json-server либо в неправильном его вызове.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шел по пути указанному в ошибке и искал указанный участок кода, но его там даже нет. Приложение ставил через npx create-next-app

Comment: В коде заметил ошибку вместо useEffect написано useEffetct, исправил, но ошибка никуда не делась

Comment: и useEffect, и concurrently, и json-server тут не при чём. давайте на минутку представим почти невозможную ситуацию, что эта проблема возникала не только у вас - шикарные перспективы [открываются](https://www.google.com/search?q=loading+chunk+node_modules+next_dist_client_dev_noop+js+failed)

Comment: Прошу прощения если мой вопрос оказался банальным, я только начал учить Next, все делал сверяясь с документацией, так и не понял в чем проблема(

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена после удаления папки .next в корне проекта и запуском новой сборки через "npm run dev".